# Make the draggable item fade away when dropped onto droppable contianer

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I have four draggable elements and a droppable area currently looking like [this (Fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/srabeat/L3abroyy/) and I would like to improve the experience by adding the following functions:

1) on start: display an alternative element as soon as it is out of its initial position.

2) on drop: draggable element fade away when it is dropped onto droppable container (e.g. ".frame").

What is the best way to do this?

Thanks, any help would be greatly appreciated!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("[id*=draggable]").draggable({
    containment: "#area51",
    revert: true,
    stack: ".frame_type"
  });
  $(".frame").droppable({
    hoverClass: "ui-state-active",

    drop: function(event, ui) {
      var currentId = $(ui.draggable).attr('id');

      if (currentId == "draggable-1") {
        $(this).css('background-color', '#f1c40f');
      } else if (currentId == "draggable-2") {
        $(this).css('background-color', '#e74c3c');
      } else if (currentId == "draggable-3") {
        $(this).css('background-color', '#3498db');
      } else if (currentId == "draggable-4") {
        $(this).css('background-color', '#9b59b6');
      }
    }

  });
});
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid text-center">
  <div class="row" id="area51">
    <div class="col-xs-8">
      <div class="showroom">
        <div class="frame">
          <img class="display" src="http://placehold.it/200" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="selection text-center">
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
          <li id="draggable-1" class="frame_type color-1"></li>
          <li id="draggable-2" class="frame_type color-2"></li>
          <li id="draggable-3" class="frame_type color-3"></li>
          <li id="draggable-4" class="frame_type color-4"></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: in #1: what do you mean by an alternative element ? you mean a clone of the element being dragged?

Answer (score 1):

1. `<li/>` elements are now shadows of their containing draggable `div` elements and tweaked styles to overlap them
2. jQuery `.hide()` is used to remove them on drag complete

I've also simplified the JS a lot. Basically you have a reference to the element all the time, so don't need to match on ID or search for it.

The CSS could use some love as I haven't spent too long on it. The widths are smaller than in your sample.

http://jsfiddle.net/pratik136/L3abroyy/10/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("[id*=draggable]").draggable({
    containment: "#area51",
    revert: true,
    stack: ".frame_type"
  });
  $(".frame").droppable({
    hoverClass: "ui-state-active",

    drop: function(event, ui) {
      var elem = ui.draggable;
      $(this).css('background-color', elem.css('background-color'));
      $(elem.parent()).hide('slow');
    }

  });
});
```

```css
/* General Styles */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #666;
}
.showroom {
  border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 500px;
  padding: 100px;
}
.frame {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 50px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.display {
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.selection {
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 500px;
}
.frame_type {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
li {
  height: 50px;
  width: 30%;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.color-1,
.color-1 div {
  background-color: #f1c40f;
}
.color-2,
.color-2 div {
  background-color: #e74c3c;
}
.color-3,
.color-3 div {
  background-color: #3498db;
}
.color-4,
.color-4 div {
  background-color: #9b59b6;
}
.ui-state-active {
  background-color: #e1e1e1 !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid text-center">
  <h1>Paintings & Frames: Interactive App</h1>

  <div class="row" id="area51">
    <div class="col-xs-8">
      <div class="showroom">
        <div class="frame">
          <img class="display" src="http://placehold.it/200" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="selection text-center">
        <h3>Draggable Frames</h3>

        <ul class="list-unstyled">
          <li class="color-1">
            <div id="draggable-1" class="frame_type"></div>
          </li>
          <li class="color-2">
            <div id="draggable-2" class="frame_type"></div>
          </li>
          <li class="color-3">
            <div id="draggable-3" class="frame_type"></div>
          </li>
          <li class="color-4">
            <div id="draggable-4" class="frame_type"></div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I appreciate your time and help but I am looking for a better/scalable approach. In their API there is an example showing how to layer functionality onto the draggable using the `start`, `drag`, and `stop` but I can't figure out how to utilize them. For example: 
`stop: function() {
           $('#draggable').hide();
        };`

Comment: That's fine, we can look at that. First though, is the end result what you are expecting?

Comment: It's a 3 steps process I think:
1- On start: draggable initial position is replaced by a passive state (e.g. gray color div).
2- On drop: draggable fade away 
3- On stop: draggable initial position is replaced by the initial state

Does it make any sense?